# Access privateRuntimeConfig in express server

Tags: vue.js, express, nuxt.js, backend

I've installed the [express-nuxt template](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template) and I was wondering how could I get access to the privateRuntimeConfig inside nuxt.config.js from express (API folder). One approach I thought about was to put the vars inside a .env file and then installing the dotenv package for the express server, but I think that using just Nuxt could be better.

Answer (score 1):

We have done precisely this by importing the Nuxt config into the file that configures the Express app, and using `defu` to combine public and private runtime configs, as Nuxt itself does:

```js
    // nuxt.config.js

    export default {
      publicRuntimeConfig: {},
      privateRuntimeConfig: { redis: { url: process.env['REDIS_URL'] } }
    };
```

```js
    // api/index.js

    import express from 'express';
    import defu  from 'defu';
    import { createClient as createRedisClient } from 'redis';
    
    const app = express();
    
    import nuxtConfig from '../nuxt.config.js';
    let runtimeConfig;
    
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (!runtimeConfig) {
        // Load Nuxt config once, at runtime
        runtimeConfig = defu(nuxtConfig.privateRuntimeConfig, nuxtConfig.publicRuntimeConfig);
      }
      next();
    });
    
    // Subsequent middlewares will then be able to read from `runtimeConfig`
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      const redisClient = createRedisClient({ url: runtimeConfig.redis.url });
      next();
    });
    
    export default app;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But what if I need the env props to connect to a DB?

Comment: I have added example Nuxt runtime config, and Express middleware, to show how you could use an environment variable to connect to Redis. This could come from the actual server environment, or Nuxt will read from a .env file if present.

Comment: What wouldn't that create a redis instance every time a request is made? Wouldn't that be unnecessary? And the DB connection is not in the same file as the the express API

Comment: And another thing, how could i use ESM in the express backend? Should I install something or how? BTW, as I said, i'm using the express-nuxt template from nuxt community

Comment: The Redis connection is just an example to illustrate the answer to your original question of how to read from Nuxt's runtime config in the context of an Express app. Exactly how you then use it depends on your use case.